# Importing data from web page with diffrent Dates in excel using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, date, html

i don't know how to import data from a web site ,which i need to do it since 1st of July 2012 until present. Any ideas guys?? I don't know how to do it since url changes. I want to import all the data since July 2012 until now so can i do it through html source of the web page?

```
Sub websitee()


With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data/intraday", Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1"))
    .Name = "intraday"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     Union(Columns(3), Columns(4), Columns(5), Columns(7), Columns(8),           Columns(9)).Delete

     End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If the URL changes when you filter by date could you not just use the new URL in your connection?

Comment: At least tell us what format the URL takes for each day! It should just be a matter of generating the URL dynamically. Do you want to continue doing this automatically every day?

Comment: its takes like this :http://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data/intraday/intraday-table/2013-02-06/FR is changing as the day,month, year changes. and i want to import all the data from 1/07/2012 until present.Yes, the ideal would me doing this automatically starting from 1/7/2012.. any ideas @ElectricLlama tnx for your comment

Comment: @Rick how could i do this? i need the url to open the page and import data

Comment: I may be missing something here but in your code where it says `"URL;http://www.......` change to the url with the date on it `URL;http://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data/intraday/intraday-table/2012-07-01/`

Comment: tnx for your comment, when i change it and run it, it imports the specific day 1/7/2012 and i want to import the whole data from 1/7/2012 to present, not just a specific day. if you have any ideas i would aprecciate it @Rick

Answer (score 2):

Next iteration: You can now call DownloadPeriod and it *should* drop the data on to a number one worksheets per day in January 2012. Please test and we can go on to the next iteration of code.

```
Sub DownloadDayFromUser()
     Dim sInput as String
     sInput = InputBox("Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format")
     Call websitee(sInput)
End Sub


Sub DownloadPeriod()
     Dim DownloadDay as Date
     DownloadDay = #1/1/2012#

     Do While DownloadDay < #1/2/2012#
         ' Create a new workbook to put the data into
         ActiveWorkBook.Worksheets.Add
         ' Call the web service for today
         Call websitee(Format(DownloadDay,"YYYY-MM-DD"))
         ' Increment the day
         DownloadDay = DownloadDay + 1
     Loop
End Sub

Sub websitee(sDate as String)


With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"URL;http://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data/intraday/" & sDate & "/", Destination:=Range( _
"$A$1"))
.Name = "intraday"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlTables
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 Union(Columns(3), Columns(4), Columns(5), Columns(7), Columns(8),           Columns(9)).Delete

 End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Tnx for your comment , i made a few corrections about the url. it really imports the table when you give as an input the date, i mean the specific date. that's great but i would like to import a specific column (the hours and the average weight, not the whole table). Do you have any ideas how can i do this?? I mean when i give as input the date i want to import the hours column and the weight average column next to each other.If you have any ideas it would be vital @ElectricLlama

Comment: epexspot will need to provide  with a special URL to retrieve just one column. Are you still interested in retrieving a range of data across different days?

Comment: OK I have updated the code. Test and get back to me and we can go on to the next iteration.