# Import web data in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to import MutualFundsPortfolioValues to Excel. I don't know how to import data from a web site which I need to do is import web data to Excel within 2 different dates of chosen companies ..

When I input dates to B3 and B4 cells and click Commandbutton1, Excel might import all data from my web-page to my Excel sheets "result"

For example:

```
date 1: 04/03/2013 <<<< " it will be in sheets "input" cell B3
date 2 : 11/04/2013 <<<<< " it will be in sheet "input " cell B4
choosen companies <<<<<< its Range "B7: B17"
```

I have added a sample excel worksheet and a printscreen of the web page..
Any ideas?

My web page url :

http://www.spk.gov.tr/apps/MutualFundsPortfolioValues/FundsInfosFP.aspx?ctype=E&submenuheader=0

Sample Excel and Sample picture of the data: 
http://uploading.com/folders/get/b491mfb6/excel-web-query

Comment: Do you have a way to automate populating the lists on that page to generate the data you want? If you cant do this then you might be better off using the "download as xls" option since you'll have to do it manually anyway.

Comment: Sidenote: might want to use another image host, lots of the popups are NSFW

Comment: how can I automate it? I need datas of the companie named Allianz on that page ...  I have added a sample excel file to  http://uploading.com/folders/get/b491mfb6/excel-web-query

Comment: The site has been designed to make automation like that difficult. You would need to use VBA and Javascript. Plus quite a bit of time, effort and luck.

Comment: can you do it for me ? If yes , I can pay 15 Us dollars for it.

Comment: I uploaded again to the another image host .   http://www.4shared.com/photo/2aC-7wB6/web_query.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/jAHir49p/web_query.html

Comment: we charge a lot more than $15 USD for doing your job for you, or is it your homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to import data using IE Automation.

> **Input Parameters** (Enter in Sheet1 as per screenshot below) 
>   start date  = B3 
>   end date = B4 
>   Şirketler  = B5 (It allows multiples values which should appear below B5 and so on)

[image]

**ViewSource of page** input fileds
[image]

**How code works :**

- The code creates object of Internet Explorer and navigates to
  [site](http://www.spk.gov.tr/apps/MutualFundsPortfolioValues/FundsInfosFP.aspx?ctype=E&submenuheader=0)
- Waits till the page is completely loaded and ready. (IE.readystate)
- Creates the object html class
- Enter the values for the input fields from Sheet1 (txtDateBegin,txtDateEnd , lstCompany)
- Clicks on the submit button
- Iterates thru each row of table dgFunds and dumps into excel Sheet2

**Code:**

```
   Dim IE As Object
Sub Website()


    Dim Doc As Object, lastRow As Long, tblTR As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True

navigate:
    IE.navigate "http://www.spk.gov.tr/apps/MutualFundsPortfolioValues/FundsInfosFP.aspx?ctype=E&submenuheader=0"

    Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set Doc = IE.document

    If Doc Is Nothing Then GoTo navigate

    Set txtDtBegin = Doc.getelementbyid("txtDateBegin")
    txtDtBegin.Value = Format(Sheet1.Range("B3").Value, "dd.MM.yyyy")

    Set txtDtEnd = Doc.getelementbyid("txtDateEnd")
    txtDtEnd.Value = Format(Sheet1.Range("B4").Value, "dd.MM.yyyy")


    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("B65000").End(xlUp).row
    If lastRow < 5 Then Exit Sub

    For i = 5 To lastRow

        Set company = Doc.getelementbyid("lstCompany")
        For x = 0 To company.Options.Length - 1
            If company.Options(x).Text = Sheet1.Range("B" & i) Then
                company.selectedIndex = x

                Set btnCompanyAdd = Doc.getelementbyid("btnCompanyAdd")
                btnCompanyAdd.Click
                Set btnCompanyAdd = Nothing

                wait
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next


    wait

    Set btnSubmit = Doc.getelementbyid("btnSubmit")
    btnSubmit.Click

    wait

    Set tbldgFunds = Doc.getelementbyid("dgFunds")
    Set tblTR = tbldgFunds.getelementsbytagname("tr")



    Dim row As Long, col As Long
    row = 1
    col = 1

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each r In tblTR

        If row = 1 Then
            For Each cell In r.getelementsbytagname("th")
                Sheet2.Cells(row, col) = cell.innerText
                col = col + 1
            Next
            row = row + 1
            col = 1
        Else
            For Each cell In r.getelementsbytagname("td")
                Sheet2.Cells(row, col) = cell.innerText
                col = col + 1
            Next
            row = row + 1
            col = 1
        End If
    Next

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

Sub wait()
    Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
    Do While IE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
End Sub
```

**Ouput table** in Sheet 2

[image]

HTH

Comment: I am getting   "Http Request Validation Error or Unexpected Http Request"  ERROR… 
Is it posible to change >>>Input Parameters start date = B3 end date = B4    Şirketler = from B5 to B15 <<<<< because I want to download more than 6 funds at the same time
Output table B20

Comment: @AcemiExcelci i have updated the code to add  more than  Şirketler  at a time.

Comment: Dear Santosh , can you upload or send me your excel workbook by e-mail please . Because I am getting runtime errors 424 ,type mismatch error etc.  ı dont know whats wrong.

Comment: Its working fine at my end.  istead of IE.Visible = True  try  IE.Visible = false.

Comment: Could you upload your workbook to a file upload site or e-mail it to me please?  my e-mail is acemiexcelci@yahoo.com.tr

Comment: I am at office and i cant for now because of restrictions. I will do it later.

Comment: thank you Dear Santosh. I will be waiting your e-mail..  please let me know how can I pay to you

Comment: Dear Santosh  , I'm hoping I hear from you before midnight . because I have a lot to do on that table

Comment: Can you confirm if the file is working and vote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could [read about it by clicking here](http://r1c1.blogspot.co.uk/2006/09/using-web-queries-to-import-data-to.html) then use the macro recorder to record doing it, this will give you some code to work with and if you need more help just ask

here is another question on Stack Overflow: [Importing data from web page with diffrent Dates in excel using VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762570/importing-data-from-web-page-with-diffrent-dates-in-excel-using-vba-code)

basically you're going to add a QueryTable object to the QueryTables collection of the Active worksheet in Excel.

Here is the MSDN reference on Query Tables: [MSDN Library: Excel 2007 Querytables Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178808%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: macro recorder didnt help.

Comment: macro recorder doesnt help.. it because page has download as xls or xml option ... also your example question link is different than mine

Comment: its different because its a different question, one that is similar to yours that might help solve your problem.

Comment: we try to encourage people who need help to do a little reading, research, write some code, we don't always just hand over the code as it won't help you learn.