# Import Data from Website

Tags: web-applications, excel, vba

I want to import data into my excel spreadsheet from a website. I initially tried to do this with a web query, however the tables I want to import don't have any data in them (when viewed through the web query wizard). Does anyone have a solution to this problem? or an alternative method of importing data?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to have the link to where the data lives?

Comment: sreen-scraping is never a great approach - web-sites get re-designed too often for this to be reliable. Best to try to find a service that is based around delivering the data to an ftp or via a csv

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959008/import-web-data-in-excel-using-vba/15962055#15962055