# Unable to get value registered by server

Tags: html, excel, events, vba, combobox

I am trying to create a VBA interface in Excel to a share trading website called SpectrumLive.

I can fill out the number of shares to buy in the relevant form on the site. However when I click the "Place Order" button it remembers the last manual value I entered rather than the value entered by the VBA.
It is like I need to raise an event or something like that to get the server side to register the value.

The field looks like a combobox with an editable text field. You can actually select predefined values via selecting the little arrow in the combobox control. However the script enters the value directly into the text field (like I can do manually as well).

I have been working on that particular problem for quite some time now and I have run out of ideas.

The VBA I use is:

theDocument.getElementsByName("ordertype").Item(i).value = "88"

for setting the quantity of shares to trade to 88.

I have tried to fire OnChange event by:

theDocument.getElementsByName("ordertype").Item(i).FireEvent ("onchange")

but with no luck.

The HTML code of that particular part of the page looks like this:

```
<div id="MenuMgr_WM_view4_widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f_ordertab_amountrow" class="formrow">

<div id="MenuMgr_WM_view4_widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f_ordertab_amountrow_error" class="error_field">

<span class="inline amount">

<label class="label" title="Quantity">Quantity:</label>

<div class="amount_type input selector" style="display:none;" name="MenuMgr$WM_view4$widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f$ordertab$amountrow$ctl00">

<span id="MenuMgr_WM_view4_widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f_ordertab_amountrow_amount" name="MenuMgr$WM_view4$widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f$ordertab$amountrow$amount">

<div id="AmountSelectorContainer">

<span id="MenuMgr_WM_view4_widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f_ordertab_amountrow_amount_AmountSelectorControl" name="MenuMgr$WM_view4$widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f$ordertab$amountrow$amount$AmountSelectorControl">

<div id="AmountSelectorDropDownList" class="left input selector" name="MenuMgr$WM_view4$widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f$ordertab$amountrow$amount$AmountSelectorControl$AmountSelectorDropDownList">

**<input class="inp aright" type="text" value="" name="ordertype" title="">**

<div class="btns">

</div>

</span>

</div>

</span>

</span>

<div class="formrow amount_info" style="display: none;"> </div>
```

Even though the "value" in the field named "ordertype" above is "" SpectrumLive displays 88 for the quantity (I had Firebug showing me which field represent the text field of the combobox).

Any help for this is most appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: [This link may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959008/import-web-data-in-excel-using-vba/15962055#15962055). If you can share the link i can try it.

Comment: @Santosh -It is a share trading site and you would need to have a user ID and password to view the actual page. The user entry is https://webtrader.spectrumlive.com/Login/en. Sorry - I can't share my login details as it gives access to my personal financial information and people could actually trade shares in my name - although I'm sure anyone can do it better than I :-) Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="inp aright" type="text" value="" name="ordertype" title="">
```

The above html is a textbox and to set its value you can use the below code.

```
 Set i_Order = theDocument.getElementsByName("ordertype")
 i_Order.Value = "88"
```

OR

```
 Set i_Amt = theDocument.getelementbyid("AmountSelectorDropDownList")
 set i_Order = i_Amt.NextSibling  '(put a breakpoint here)
 i_Order.Value = "88"
```

(Goto immediate window and put this text`?i_order.OuterHTML` on debug mode which will let you know if you got the ordertype textbox. If it doesn't work you may try this `set i_Order = i_Amt.NextSibling.NextSibling`)

Also i dont see any javascript change event attached to textbox no need to use FireEvent.

Comment: I did post an answer but somehow it hasn't come throug. The first solution gave "not supported" and the second one gave "not set". I managed to get a value into the quantity field, but have now an issue with clicking a toggle button. I will create a separate entry for that. Great if you could have a look at that when it comes through. Thanks heaps for your help!