# How to select and change a drop down list in VBA without having an ID

Tags: vba

So I have been struggling to find a way to select a drop down list on this particular web page and change the value in it. I have looked at dozens of examples of code from other people, but they are all finding the element by ID, which the element I am searching does not have an ID, nor does any other element on the web page. The only unique value the element has is the name=. This would be simple and straightforward if the element had an ID, but I have not found any code that can help me if the element does not have an ID. What I have been trying so far is what you see below, but it does not seem to work. If anyone could help me to know how to select the element by name, and then change the selection from the drop down menu I would be extremely grateful. Thank you.

My code so far looks like this:

```
    For x = 1 To agent1.explorer.document.body.all.Length - 1
            temp = ""
            If agent1.explorer.document.body.all(x).Name = "advsearch_contents_objecttypectrl_0" Then
                agent1.explorer.document.body.all(x).Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

I am iterating through the elements in the web page to find the one I want, however, it never selects the correct one and I am out of ideas.

The element that I am trying to select is in a Select Tag and name = "advsearch_contents"

There are multiple selections to choose from in the drop down list, but the value I want to set is sales_contracts

Thank you for taking your time to lend a hand. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Set agent= agent1.explorer.document.getElementsByName("advsearch_contents_objecttypectrl_0")

        For x = 0 To agent.Options.Length - 1
            If agent.Options(x).Text = "sales_contracts" Then
                agent.selectedIndex = x
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

If it does not work request you to add the html source of page in your post. Also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873082/unable-to-get-value-registered-by-server) for alternative way.