# Make the exportation of data occur for a chosen date

Tags: internet-explorer, date, excel, vba

I have Excel code which gets into intranet:

```vb
sub TESTE()

Dim Data As Date
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

URL = "(URL address)"
ie.navigate (URL)

Data = Date - 1

ie.document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl03_ddDropDownButton").Click ' Calendario
ie.document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").Value = Format(Data, "dd/mm/yyyy") ' Data
ie.document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl00").Click ' Exibir Relatório

URL = "(URL address)"
ie.navigate (URL)

End Sub
```

However, in the last line of the code, the exportation doesn´t occur by the chosen date, it always considers today. What can I do to make the exportation consider a chosen date?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959008/import-web-data-in-excel-using-vba/15962055#15962055) may be helpful.

Comment: Because after the second navigate(), you do not set the chosen date. Why do you navigate twice?

Comment: For Each ele In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
        If ele.classname = "ActiveLink" Then
          If ele.innertext = "Excel" Then
            ele.Click
          Exit For
          End If
        End If
    Next


ie.Visible = True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Application.SendKeys ("%+s")
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

ie.Quit
 Resolved

Answer (score 0):

Some macro that triggers e-mail in accordance with responsible?
Ex: Fulando responsible for category A, category B bentrano responsible for, I want a macro to do this separation and forward e-mail to the responsible right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Extrai_MIS()

Dim data As Date
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

URL = "(URL address)"

    Do
        DoEvents
     Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

ie.Visible = True

data = Range("A4")

If Range("Q1") < data Then
ie.Quit
MsgBox ("Não contém informações nessa data, escolha outra."), vbCritical, "ATENÇÃO:"
Exit Sub
End If

ie.document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl03_ddDropDownButton").Click ' Calendario
ie.document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl03_txtValue").Value = Format(data, "dd/mm/yyyy") ' Data
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10") ' Tempo para carregar a pagina
ie.document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl04_ctl00").Click ' Exibir Relatório
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readystate = 4

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

    For Each ele In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
    If ele.classname = "ActiveLink" Then
    If ele.innertext = "Excel" Then
    ele.Click
     Exit For
          End If
        End If
    Next
ie.Visible = True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Application.SendKeys ("%+s")
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

ie.Quit

ChDir Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\rpt_visoes_orders_today.xls"
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
End Sub
```